# How to block Spam SMS messages from contacts without number?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, spam, sms-blocking

I receive spam from "Bubbleroom" contact without contact details after pressing three dots regularly. 
I am thinking how you can block messages from "no phone number" and such cases. 
Those messages are just advertisements.

Fig. 1 Example 1, Fig. 2 Example 2 of spam messages

[image]
[image]

It would be great to do it without 3rd party application. 
I know the thread [Block SMS without number](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/block-sms-without-number) but it only offers 3rd party applications.

Phone: oneplus 3T
Android: 8.0 Oreo

Comment: which Android version? Is your device rooted

Comment: I'd also check with installed apps having the permission to write SMS (not necessarily send). Could be some "adware".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block SMS without number](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/block-sms-without-number)

Comment: @TimothyLanger Not, because I do not want to use 3rd party apps and do as much as possible without them. Please, read the body.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 you could e.g. use one of the [Permission Checker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379) (link goes to my site). Those should list all permissions – not just those Google deems the user worthy to see :) If you found some likely candidates, you could either uninstall them and see if the issue goes away – or first check e.g. at AppBrain what libraries they have and whether some ad libs are among them (if no libs are listed for an app, it might not yet have been scanned, though).

Comment: @Izzy Done with AppBrain Ads now, but still not sure if any app is causing. How can you differentiate if the SMS coming from someone else trying to spam me?

Comment: I cannot. Neither did I say it *definitely is* adware – just that it's possible. And especially with SMS, only few apps should be permitted to write them. An app that has not to deal with SMS should not have that permission. So if there is an app matching this description (having the permission without the need), it's a likely candidate.

Comment: Those "no phone number" have numbers but it is hidden. I was able to see them but using an iPhone thought...